# Can we add detection of Minecraft Bedrock Edition's NBT questions to the question asking process?

Tags: feature-request, questions, minecraft, asking

Can individual sites add features to the question asking procedure? If yes, could Gaming SE add a way to detect NBT questions in Minecraft Bedrock Edition and then ask the user whether [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/171580) already fixes their issue?

There is one of these questions every few days and the answer is "you can't do that" almost every single time. The site usually suggests that in the closing dialogue, but it still requires manual effort by 5 people with sufficient privileges every single time. These questions occur because people find commands online, copy-paste them into their game and get an error message.

Detecting them with reasonable accuracy is pretty simple:

- Either…

  - the tag [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) is used or…
  - the question mentions "pocked edition"/"bedrock edition"/"android"/"windows 10"/… and has the [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) tag
- … and this Regex finds at least one result (within one line):

  - `(?:\@.\[.*nbt\=|clear|data|execute|fill|give|loot|replaceitem|scoreboard|setblock|summon).*\{.*\}`
    This essentially just checks for something like "`@e[type=cow,nbt=`" or one of the commands that has NBT in them (or `/scoreboard`, because that used to have an NBT component until 1.12), followed by `{`, then more stuff, then `}`.